# get specific output in linux after string

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, text-processing, string

```
Controller loading lists...
-------------------------------------------------
command: select SERVICE_NAME from <table_name>
-------------------------------------------------
        SERVICE_NAME
1       first service
2       second service
```

i need to filter out this output in Linux and get the result as

`first_service,second_service`

Comment: Is it one record per file, or are records concatenated (i.e. it restarts at the bottom with `Controller loading lists...` or similar)?

Comment: You would do this in the database engine (using e.g. `GROUP_CONCAT()` or similar functionality), not by postprocessing the output. Unfortunately, you never say what SQL database backend you're using.

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU `sed`

```
$ sed -Ez 's/[^0-9]*[^[:alpha:]]*([^ ]*) ([^\n]*)\n?/\1_\2,/g;s/,$/\n/' input_file
first_service,second_service
```

Comment: @LeoShukla Did you copy and paste the code correctly? I have added an optional new line in case that is where your issue is. You can check here for a demo https://ideone.com/F3AMmC

Answer (score 0):

There's definitely room for improvement in this solution. If I was better with `sed`, I feel like this out to be condensable into a single invocation of `sed`.  Even the `grep` could be eliminated if I knew how to tell `sed` to delete pattern spaces that don't begin with a string of digits.  Better still would likely be `awk`.

```
grep -E '^[0-9]+' input_file |
    sed -E -e 's/^[0-9]+ +//' -e 's/ /_/g' |
    sed -e ':a' -e 'N;$!ba' -e 's/\n/,/g'

$ cat << EOF > input_file
Controller loading lists...
-------------------------------------------------
command: select SERVICE_NAME from <table_name>
-------------------------------------------------
        SERVICE_NAME
1       first service
2       second service
39      third of four
427     fourth and final service
EOF
$ grep -E '^[0-9]+' input_file |
    sed -E -e 's/^[0-9]+ +//' -e 's/ /_/g' |
    sed -e ':a' -e 'N;$!ba' -e 's/\n/,/g'
first_service,second_service,third_of_four,fourth_and_final_service
```

Comment: "1 first_service,2 second_service" - this is the output that i am getting with this one . looks like the numbers also need to be removed

Comment: @LeoShukla Thanks for the feedback.  Edited.  Seems the `sed` syntax I tried originally needs to be broken up a little.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -e 'my $i=0; my @a; for lines() {  \
            $i=1 and next if /^ \s+ SERVICE_NAME /;  \
            if ($i.Bool) { @a.push: .words.skip.join("_") } else {next};};  \
            .put for @a.join(",");'  file
```

OR

```perl
~$ raku -e 'my @a; for lines() {  \
            @a.push( $_.words.skip.join: "_" ) if /^ \s+ SERVICE_NAME / ^fff * }; \
            .put for @a.join(",");'  file
```

Sample Input:

```
Controller loading lists...
-------------------------------------------------
command: select SERVICE_NAME from <table_name>
-------------------------------------------------
        SERVICE_NAME
1       first service
2       second service
```

Sample Output:

```
first_service,second_service
```

Raku is a programming language in the Perl-family. The project was started in year 2000 by Larry Wall and colleagues. The first release was in December 2015. The Perl6 language was renamed **Raku** in 2019.

First answer above: the code declares a scalar `$i` and an array `@a`. Input is taken with `lines()`. Inside the `{...}` block, a sentinel line `^ \s+ SERVICE_NAME` is searched for. If found, `$i` is set to `1` and the code proceeds to the `next` line.

From here, the last two statements run if `$i` coerced to a `Bool`ean is `True`. When `$i.Bool` is `True`, the `{...}` block is entered: the line is broken into whitespace separated `.words`, the first word (i.e. the number) is `skip`ped and the remainder `join`ed with underscores. Finally, the line is out`put`, `join`ed with commas.

Second answer above: The code uses Raku's `sed`-like "flip-flop" operator, `fff` and variants. The `^fff` variant in the code turns ON for capturing lines at the line after the `SERVICE_NAME` sentinel line is found. The `*` means all lines until the end of the target file are `push`ed onto the array. See discussion above for text-processing and out`put`.

[https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#infix_^fff](https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#infix_%5Efff)
https://raku.org